# Не получается подключить либу Python на Windows

Tags: python

На **linux** было введено две команды

```
sudo pacman -S dictd
sudo apt-get install dictd
```

Как сделать тоже самое на **Windows** не нашел, пытался так:

```
pip install pacman
pip install dictd
```

Но, естественно, ничего не получилось.***Как это сделать?***

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/143996/

Comment: не получилось почему? pip не нашел, или в чем другом проблема?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/947220/how-to-install-packages-apt-get-install-in-windows

Comment: Главная проблема в том, что не нашел pip